# Deciding The region To Evaluate $\iint_{R}\left(x-y+1\right)dx dy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> **Question**Evaluate $$\iint_{R}\left(x-y+1\right)dxdy$$ where
>   $R$ is region inside the unit square in which $ x +y\geq \dfrac{1}{2}$

**My Approach**

**Figure** 
I don't know how to plot graph In latex.I don't know anything
about latex coding.

Picture of region
[image]

In the figure There would be a unit square in first quadrant having
origin as one of its vertex .Straight line $\left(\frac{x}{\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{y}{\frac{1}{2}}=1\right)$divides
the unit square in two regions R$_{1}$and R$_{2}$. Where R$_{1}$region
is below the line and R$_{2}$region is above the line.

I think The region of integration $R= R_{2}$

$$\iint_{R_{2}}\left(x-y+1\right)dxdy=\iint_{R_{1}\cup R_{2}}\left(x-y+1\right)dxdy-\iint_{R_{1}}\left(x-y+1\right)dxdy$$
$\Longrightarrow$ 
This
is very easy to calculate.

**Book Answer** Books answer comes from This calculation

$$\iint_{R_{1}}\left(x-y+1\right)dxdy = \iint_{R_{1}\cup R_{2}}\left(x-y+1\right)dxdy - \iint_{R_{2}}\left(x-y+1\right)dxdy $$ $\Longrightarrow$

Region of integration is $R= R_{1}$

Am I wrong or is the book?

Comment: You can **attach** diagrams, no need to plot in LaTeX (or MathJaX)...and the region "above the line" is not a simple one: first you have the triangle $\;-x+\frac12\le y\le 1 , 0\le x\le\frac12\;$ , and to this you must add the integral over the region $\;\frac12\le x\le 1 ,  0\le y\le 1\;$ = a rectangle. You better attach a diagram or stuff.

Comment: @DonAntonio I have added the photo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[15px,#ffc]{\ds{\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x - y + 1}\bracks{x + y \geq {1 \over 2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y}}\qquad\pars{~\bracks{\cdots}:\ Iverson\ Bracket~}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x - y + 1}\bracks{x \geq {1 \over 2} - y}
\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{{1 \over 2} - y < 0}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x - y + 1}
\,\dd x\,\dd y +
\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{0 < {1 \over 2} - y < 1}\int_{1/2 - y}^{1}\pars{x - y + 1}
\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[1cm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{y > {1 \over 2}}\pars{{1 \over 2} - y + 1}\,\dd y
\\[2mm] + &\
\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{-\,{1 \over 2} < y < {1 \over 2}}\bracks{{1 \over 2}- {1 \over 2}\pars{{1 \over 2} - y}^{2} - \pars{y - 1}\pars{{1 \over 2} + y}}\,\dd y
\\[1cm] = &\
\int_{1/2}^{1}\pars{{3 \over 2} - y}\,\dd y +
\int_{0}^{1/2}\pars{{7 \over 8} + y - {3 \over 2}\,y^{2}}\,\dd y =
\bbx{7 \over 8} = 0.875
\end{align}

Comment: $R_2$ is the region you're looking for, not $R_1$

Comment: Thanks. [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) are very convenient in the evaluation of 'cumbersome' regions. At least for me because I'm very bad when I try to draw something.

Comment: @FelixMarin hey brother i am very much new to the concept of iverson bracket.I haven't heared it,before you mentioned it in your answer.Can you suggest me textbook which contains the concept of iversion bracket and its applications{ especially in Integration}.

Comment: @MohanSharma I already gave  above the link to the
[Wikipedia Iverson Bracket page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).